# Add clientIds dynamically to API annotation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a java Appengine application which uses google endpoints frameworks.

I have a set of client ids that consume my api key and those client ids may change in some intervals due to new applications coming up to consume my api.

I need to maintain an array of client ids so that no other user can access my api other than present in my list.

Due to which i need to re-deploy my code to cloud platform each time i add a client id.

**"@Api"** being an annotation i cannot assign value to it dynamically because annotations are considered at compile time.

So is there anyway that i can add client ids without re-deploying the code again and again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need dynamic client IDs, you need to write a custom `Authenticator`, which you will put in your `@Api` annotation. You can base it on [the existing authenticators](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/tree/master/endpoints-framework/src/main/java/com/google/api/server/spi/auth). Then, have your authenticator check a dynamic source (e.g. Cloud SQL), rather than the annotation value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer saiyr, but i am a bit lost in the entire flow of the existing authenticators that you provided me to base my `Authenticator` on!! Can you please guide me on what all packages and classes i need customise?

Comment: It depends precisely on what your use case is, or more specifically, what authentication mechanism you're using. If you're using only JWT token auth, then you can create a copy of [`GoogleJwtAuthenticator`](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/blob/master/endpoints-framework/src/main/java/com/google/api/server/spi/auth/GoogleJwtAuthenticator.java) that replaces the `checkClientId` call with your own method that checks a dynamic client ID list.

Comment: Thanks saiyr, It was really helpful :)